# SQL for columns A, B, C: group by A, compute share of B equals C for each A

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

Database is Oracle. I have a single table with three columns, A, B and C.

- A is a string column
- B is an int column
- C is an int column

I need an SQL select that groups on  A and returns the share (in percent) where B = C = [particular int value] for each value of A.

Something like

```
SELECT A, percentBEqC
...
GROUP ON A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT A
     , COUNT( CASE WHEN B = C AND C = 256
                   THEN 1
              END 
            )
       / COUNT(*) AS percentBEqC
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY A
```

You may want to check if `B = 256 AND C = 256` has better performance.

---

Another way for your problem would be:

```
SELECT ta.A
     , COALESCE(cnt,0) / cntAll AS percentBEqC
FROM
    ( SELECT A
           , COUNT(*) AS cntAll
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP BY A
    ) ta
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT A
           , COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM YourTable
      WHERE B = 256 AND C = 256
      GROUP BY A
    ) ts
    ON ts.A = ta.A
```

Comment: Regarding B=256 AND C=256 for better performance: These is no index on the particular table, so I think it doesn't matter (in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Another way:
<sub>..once the syntax is correct ;/</sub>

```
SELECT A, (COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytbl b WHERE b.A = a.A)) AS percentBEqC
  FROM mytbl a
 WHERE B = particular_value
   AND C = particular_value
 GROUP BY A;
```

Returns only rows where percentBEqC > 0,

Comment: `GROUP BY`, not `GROUP ON` ;)